# Create Dataframe out of distances and id's between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, distance

I'll try to explain what I'm currently working with:
I have two dataframes: one for Gas Station A (165 stations), and other for Gas Station B (257 stations). They both share the same format:

```
id    Coor
1    (a1,b1)
2    (a2,b2)
```

Coor has tuples with the location coordinates. What I want to do is to add 3 columns to Dataframe A with nearest Competitor #1, #2 and #3 (from Gas Station B).
Currently I managed to get every distance from A to B (42405 distance measures), but in a list format:

```
distances=[]
for (u,v) in gasA['coor']:
    for (w,x) in gasB['coor']:
        distances.append(sp.distance.euclidean((u,v),(w,x)))
```

This lets me have the values I need, but I still need to match them with the ID from Gas Station A, and get the top 3. I have the suspicion working with lists is not the best approach here. Do you have any suggestions?

Edit: as suggested, first 5 rows are:
in GasA:

```
id           coor
60712    (-333525363206695,-705191013427772)
60512    (-333539879388388, -705394161580837)
60085    (-333545609177068, -703168832659184)
60110    (-333601677229216, -705167284798638)
60078    (-333608898397271, -707213099595404)
```

in GasB:

```
    id           coor
70174    (-333427160000000,-705459060000000)
70223    (-333523030000000, -706705470000000)
70383    (-333549270000000, -705320990000000)
70162    (-333556960000000, -705384750000000)
70289    (-333565850000000, -705104360000000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
import numpy as np
```

Creating the data:

```
 A = pd.DataFrame({'id':['60712','60512','60085', '60110','60078'], 'coor':[ (-333525363206695,-705191013427772),\
                                                                           (-333539879388388, -705394161580837),\
                                                                           (-333545609177068, -703168832659184),\
                                                                           (-333601677229216, -705167284798638),\
                                                                          (-333608898397271, -707213099595404)]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'id':['70174','70223','70383', '70162','70289'], 'coor':[ (-333427160000000,-705459060000000),\
                                                                               (-333523030000000, -706705470000000),\
                                                                               (-333549270000000, -705320990000000),\
                                                                                (-333556960000000, -705384750000000),\
                                                                              (-333565850000000, -705104360000000)]})
```

Calculating the distances:

```
res = euclidean_distances(list(A.coor), list(B.coor))
```

Selecting top 3 closest stations from B and appending to a column in A:

```
d = []
for i, id_ in enumerate(A.index):
    distances = np.argsort(res[i])[0:3] #select top 3
    distances = B.iloc[distances]['id'].values
    d.append(distances)
A = A.assign(dist=d)
```

edit

result of running with example:

```
   coor id  dist
0   (-333525363206695, -705191013427772)    60712   [70223, 70174, 70162]
1   (-333539879388388, -705394161580837)    60512   [70223, 70289, 70174]
2   (-333545609177068, -703168832659184)    60085   [70223, 70174, 70162]
3   (-333601677229216, -705167284798638)    60110   [70223, 70174, 70162]
4   (-333608898397271, -707213099595404)    60078   [70289, 70383, 70162]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks Maria! The code works like a charm, but I have a little question. I was checking locations with their actual addresses, and I have the little suspicion that this code is giving me the top 3 of the most far away neighbors. For instance, I got a 37km difference with the first neighbor. I'm sure it has to be easy to change the sorting so it is the other way around but I have never used argsort. Do you know how can I do that?

Comment: distances = np.argsort(res[i])[0:3] - just remove the [::-1]

Comment: That's the same as distances = np.argsort(res[i])[::-1][-3:], right ? I was trying that approach, but I guess it's the same. Thank you a lot, anyways !

Comment: the [::-1] reverses a lists order. :-) No need for that, I edited it out of my answer as well.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It's officialy the best answer, after manually checking some addresses now they are actually very close. Have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
a = gasA.coor.values
b = gasB.coor.values 

c = np.sum(np.sum((a[:,None,::-1] - b)**2, axis=1), axis=0)
```

we can get the numpy arrays for the coordinates for both and then broadcast a to represent all it's combinations and then take the euclidean distance.

Answer (score 0):

Define a function that calculates the distances from A to all B's and returns indices of B with the three smallest distances.

```
def get_nearest_three(row):
    (u,v) = row['Coor']
    dist_list = gasB.Coor.apply(sp.distance.euclidean,args = [u,v])
    # want indices of the 3 indices of B with smallest distances
    return list(np.argsort(dist_list))[0:3]

gasA['dists'] = gasA.apply(get_nearest_three, axis = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks xyzjayne! I tried your suggestion, but I'm getting this error when running the last command: ValueError: ('array must not contain infs or NaNs', 'occurred at index 5'). Even though I checked there are no NaNs nor infs in the coordinates. What could be happening?

Comment: I'm not sure, this sounds like an issue with either A or B. Check datatype maybe? ````for i in gasA['Coor']:print(type(i))````

Comment: I get only: <class 'tuple'> , for all of the elements both in gasA and gasB. The actual data has more than 2 columns, but I don't think that's the issue, right?

Comment: Please post more data (with first 10 rows and all columns) so I can experiment. Thanks.

Comment: This error message is a scipy thing, so probably gasB has an invalid datapoint somewhere.

Comment: There I posted some actual data (first 5 rows of both datasets). Is there a faster way to do this with all columns in the data?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a cross join (matching every row by every row between both datasets) which should be manageable with your small sets, 165 X 257, then calculate the distance. Then, rank by distance and filter for top 3.

```
cj_df = pd.merge(gasA.assign(key=1), gasB.assign(key=1), 
                 on="key", suffixes=['_A', '_B'])

cj_df['distance'] = cj_df.apply(lambda row: sp.distance.euclidean(row['Coor_A'], 
                                                                  row['Coor_B']),
                                axis = 1)

# RANK BY DISTANCE
cj_df['rank'] = .groupby('id_A')['distance'].rank()

# FILTER FOR TOP 3
top3_df = cj_df[cj_df['rank'] <= 3].sort_values(['id_A', 'rank'])
```

Comment: Thanks, parfait. I tried what you suggested, but when I run

cj_df['distance'] = cj_df.apply(lambda row: sp.distance.euclidean(row['Coor_A'], 
                                                                  row['Coor_B'])


I get the following error: KeyError: ('coor_A', 'occurred at index id_A')
Do you know what might be happening?

Comment: Whoops, since you are running rowwise operations, add `axis=1`. See edit.

Comment: Thanks, now it's working correctly! I'm quite close, because the code above gives me a 771 row dataframe (257 times 3), but I should be getting a 495 row df (165 times 3). I tried changing the code to groupby('id_B'), but that brings a 1155 row df when computing top3_df. I'll try to modify it to make it work like it should, but do you know what could be the issue?

Comment: Really? *id_A* is the groupby variable. I also noticed you need *ID* to match. Add that in the `on` clause of `merge`. I should have pointed out also that *rank* will bring over ties should distances equal.

Comment: When adding id the merge fails, but, I think there's no problem on how the merge is working. The rank is having an issue, because I should get, on every id_A, 257 different ranks (if there's no ties). e.g. But now I'm getting 1 rank for every id_A. My first id_A is 60712, and I'm getting 60 on the column 'rank' , for every row that has id_A=60712. As I see the groupby should be fine, but I can't grasp why it isn't working

Comment: But also, if I run:  sorted(cj_df['rank'].unique()) , ranks go from 1 to 242, which is around the range I should be getting, save for the ties

Comment: See update using `rank` and not `transform('rank')`. This worked on your example datasets yielding a dataframe of 15 rows.